# Assignment makes integer from a pointer without a cast

Tags: c

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(argc!=3) {
        printf("You must pass exactly three para \n");
        return 0; 
    }

    char *buffer = argv[1];
    //printf("The length of the buffer string is %d\n",buflen);
    char *mystring = argv[2];
    //printf("The length of the user string is %d\n",len);
    addstring(buffer, mystring);
    return 0; 
}

int addstring(char *buffer, char *mystring)
{
    int buflen = strlen(buffer);
    int len = strlen(mystring);
    char *dest;
    *dest = (char *)malloc(buflen + len + 1);
    printf("The size of destination is %lu\n",sizeof(dest));

    dest = strcpy(dest,buffer);
    dest = (dest + buflen);
    dest = strcpy(dest,mystring);
    printf("The final string is %p",dest);
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, the function `addstring(..)` shoes this error `Assignment makes integer from a pointer without a cast`. I know I'm taking the value of a pointer and putting it in integer, but how may I do it to resolve this error?

Comment: You have done `*dest = (char *)malloc(buflen + len + 1);` instead of `dest =malloc(buflen + len + 1);`

Comment: You need `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>`

Answer (score 1):

Even after changing `*dest` to `dest`, your function `addstring` is not works properly.. Simply try like this

```
int addstring(char *buffer, char *mystring)
{
 int buflen = strlen(buffer);
 int len = strlen(mystring);
 char *dest;
 dest = (char *)malloc(buflen + len + 1);
 printf("The size of destination is %d\n",sizeof(dest));

 strcpy(dest,buffer);
 strcat(dest,mystring);
 printf("The final string is %s\n",dest);
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have done

```
*dest = (char *)malloc(buflen + len + 1);
```

instead of

```
dest =malloc(buflen + len + 1);
```

Your program saying warning to me for this line

```
    printf("The size of destination is %lu\n",sizeof(dest));
```

`sizeof()` return type is not long unsigned int.

So use `%d` or `%u` or `%zu` as a access specifier in `printf()` statement.

Comment: `sizeof` returns type `size_t`, so conversion specifier should be `%zu`. Or if it's not supported by the compiler, then with explicit cast `printf("%u\n",(unsigned)sizeof(dest));`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have corrected my mistakes

Answer (score 0):

change

```
char *dest;
*dest = (char *)malloc(buflen + len + 1);
```

to

```
char *dest;
dest = (char *)malloc(buflen + len + 1);
```

EDIT: As @POW said, you need not cast the result of malloc

Comment: Don't cast `malloc` result

Comment: How is this different from the comment already posted? If you are going to post a comment as an answer, at least take the time to explain the reasoning behind your answer.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I haven't seen the comment while posting my answer. Same answers might get posted in fraction of few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issue in your code.
Please check the below code

```
int addstring(char *buffer, char *mystring)
{
   int buflen = strlen(buffer);
   int len = strlen(mystring);
   char *dest;
   /* No need to type-cast the malloc() */
   dest = malloc(buflen + len + 1); /* *dest holds the value, dest holds the address */
   printf("The size of destination is %lu\n",sizeof(dest));

   strcpy(dest,buffer);
   strcpy(dest+buflen,mystring);/* copy the second string to dest after buffer is copied */
   printf("The final string is %s\n",dest); /*To print a string use %s, %p is to print pointer*/
   return 0;
}
```